# How to exclude some fields when listing Grails domain?

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm, render, grails-domain-class

I'm wondering how can I list Grails domain and exclude some fields at same time. I'm guessing solution must be simple but I just can not see it.

I prepared some example with domain User:

```
class User implements Serializable {
    String username
    String email
    Date lastUpdated
    String password
    Integer status

    static constraints = { }  

    static mapping = { }
}
```

At this point I want to list all users which have status below 2.

```
render User.findAllByStatusLessThen(2) as JSON
```

I want to render JSON response to clientside without some fields. For example I just want to render users with fields ***username*** and ***lastUpdated*** so rendered JSON would look like this:

```
[{"username": "user1", "lastUpdated":"2016-09-21 06:49:46"}, {"username": "user2", "lastUpdated":"2016-09-22 11:24:42"}]
```

What's the easiest way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah.It's simple.Try below solutions

1. Solution 1

   ```
   List userList = User.where{ status < 2 }.property("username").property("lastUpdated").list()

   render userList as JSON
   ```

`output`

```
   [{"user1", "2016-09-21 06:49:46"}, {"user2", "2016-09-22 11:24:42"}]
```

2. Solution 2 - using this you will get output in the `Key-Value` pair

   ```
   List userList = User.findAllByStatusLessThen(2)?.collect{
       [username : it.username, lastUpdated: it.lastUpdated]}

   render userList as JSON
   ```

`output`

```
    [{"username": "user1", "lastUpdated":"2016-09-21 06:49:46"}, {"username": "user2", "lastUpdated":"2016-09-22 11:24:42"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Solution 2 suits the best in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for Grails **[projections](http://grails.asia/grails-criteria-projections-examples)**.

```
def result = Person.createCriteria().list {
    lt("status", 2)
    projections {
        property('username')
        property('lastUpdated')
    }
} as JSON
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want the result to be in `key-value` pair you can take advantage of `HQL` query

```
def query = """select new map(u.username as username, u.lastUpdated as lastUpdated) from User u where status < 2"""  
def result = User.executeQuery(query)
println (result as JSON)
```

This will give you the output as below

```
[{"username": "user1", "lastUpdated":"2016-09-21 06:49:46"}, {"username": "user2", "lastUpdated":"2016-09-22 11:24:42"}]
```